# Combine date and time string into one Date in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) and a [Select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) with the time added manually.

The DatePicker returns: Wed Feb 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)

The Select returns: 7:00 AM

```
const date = 'Wed Feb 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)';
const time = '7:00 AM';
console.log(new Date(date + time));
```

I receives the error: Invalid Date

I have also tried:

```
    const date = 'Wed Feb 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)';
    const time = '7:00 AM';

    const yy = new Date(date).getFullYear();
    const mm = new Date(date).getMonth() + 1;
    const dd = new Date(date).getDate();
    const completeDate = new Date(mm + dd + yy + time);


    console.log(yy);
    console.log(mm);
    console.log(dd);
    console.log(completeDate);
```

How can I combine them into one Date to save it in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that time part of date string will always be `00:00:00`

```
    const date = 'Wed Feb 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)';
    const time = '7:00 AM';
    const t1: any = time.split(' ');
    const t2: any = t1[0].split(':');
    t2[0] = (t1[1] === 'PM' ? (1*t2[0] + 12) : t2[0]);
    const time24 = (t2[0] < 10 ? '0' + t2[0] : t2[0]) + ':' + t2[1];
    const completeDate = date.replace("00:00", time24.toString());
```

**Note:**

you don't need

```
    const time24 = (t2[0] < 10 ? '0' + t2[0] : t2[0]) + ':' + t2[1] + ':00';
    const completeDate = date.replace("00:00:00", time24.toString());
```

because `date.replace` will always replace the first match.

Comment: Hi, can I remove the last two lines then? How would it be?

Comment: so sorry i wasn't clear. if u inspect closely you will see in line 1 last part `+ ':00'` is extra and in line 2 `"00:00"` became `"00:00:00"`

Comment: @IftifarTaz I am getting an error 'TypeError: date.replace is not a function'. Can you please help

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. For meridian convert the time into 24 hour format

```
    const date = 'Wed Feb 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)';
    d = new Date(date);
    const time = '7:00';
    d.setHours(time.split(':')[0]);
    d.setMinutes(time.split(':')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below approach -

```
const date = 'Wed Feb 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)';
const time = '7:00 AM';
const yy = new Date(date).getFullYear();
const mm = new Date(date).getMonth() + 1;    
const dd = new Date(date).getDate();

var interMedDt = new Date(mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yy);
interMedDt.setHours((time.split(' ')[0]).split(':')[0]);
interMedDt.setMinutes((time.split(' ')[0]).split(':')[1]);
```

Comment: Hi my friend, thanks for your answer. With your code I receives `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.` Any idea?. I have changed `var` with `let`because the IDE was complaining about it. The error is still present.

Comment: Hi, you can paste code in console and enter interMedDt, this will give you full date with hours. Are you trying to assign string to number anywhere in code ?

Comment: if some where in code you are assigning string to number then conversion is required, just add '+' in front of string var that you have it will get convert to number, this is short hand syntax to convert string to number.

Comment: Hi, I'm not assigning anything in my code at this moment, just copy/paste your code and I receives the warning. I tried `interMedDt.setHours(+(time.split(' ')[0]).split(':')[0]);` but still receiving the error. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, there must be some other part of your code which is throwing this error, if you try to copy and paste the code given in answer and do console.log(interMedDt), you will get expected result. If you can paste full code, you will get more help.

Answer (score 0):

It work and also manage the AM/PM

```
  const date = 'Wed Feb 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)';
  const time = '7:00 AM';

  const yy = new Date(date).getFullYear();
  const mm = new Date(date).getMonth() + 1;
  const dd = new Date(date).getDate();
  times=time.split(" ")[0].split(":");
  if(time.split(" ")[1]=="PM")times[0]=Number(times[0])+12;


  const completeDate = new Date(yy, mm, dd, times[0], times[1]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. With your code I receives the error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

Comment: You can solve it by converting to string: `String(Number(times[0])+12)` or `Number(times[0])+12+""`

Comment: Hi, I applied the changes but I'm still receiving the error. `times` is a different variable or do you mean `this.time`?

Comment: No maybe you need to change this `times=time.split(" ")[0].split(":");` in `const times=time.split(" ")[0].split(":");` 
I tried the code here : https://es6console.com/js0h9uui/

Comment: It's not working for me. First, you have `times` as `const` then you try to assign a value to `const` which, as far as I know, we can't do that. Second, I receives the error `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'` above `times[0]`, I tried to do `Number(times[0])` but didn't work. I'm a little confused.

Comment: About `const`, it's true, you can use `var` instead. About the error, if you use the code I wrote you can't have that error because the assignment to times[0] is a string. https://es6console.com/js0kix0v/ in the link there is the version with `var`